# How to concatenate WPF DataBindings for reuse?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Say you have a data binding in XAML that takes as input an instance of type `Apple` and results in an instance of type `Banana`.

An interface you want to leverage takes a `DataBinding` whose job it is to convert from an `Apple` to a `Cherry`. Obviously, it is a relatively simple conversion from a `Banana` to a `Cherry`, so what you decide to do is to create a second data binding in XAML that performs this `Banana` to `Cherry` conversion.

Now, you can go from A to B and B to C, but how can you concatenate the two so that you can pass in a full-fledged `DataBinding` capable of converting an `Apple` to a `Cherry`?

This doesn't have to be possible in vanilla WPF, and I'm happy to write code. I wouldn't be surprised, for example, if it called for something like a `ConcatenatedDataBinding` class with a new property for a list of input data bindings.

Thank you!

Comment: What you are saying is not very clear but converting an object to something else is NOT the job of the view (interface). If your trying to display different type of object in the same control then what you want is a DataTemplate.depending on the type of the object your items can display in various way all at once.

Answer (score 0):

If one wants to combine multiple data bindings to achieve a specific projection, one uses the [MultiBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding(v=vs.110).aspx) found in Xaml which allows for many objects to be bound and via a specialized converter ( [IMultiValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.100).aspx)) provide a unique result.

Otherwise if one has a list of disparate objects which need to be handled in a single binding then the use of a [Composite Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742405.aspx) storage can be used to process objects of differing classes but provide a single result.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the exact `DataContext`s and property change notification, your description sounds something like:

```
public Apple Apple { get; set; }
public Banana Banana { get; set; }
public Cherry Cherry { get; set; }

...

void OnLoad() {

  SetBinding(
    "Banana",
    new Binding("Apple") {
      Converter = (IValueConverter) FindResource("AppleToBananaConverter"),
      Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
    }
  );

  SetBinding(
    "Cherry",
    new Binding("Banana") {
      Converter = (IValueConverter) FindResource("BananaToCherryConverter"),
      Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
    }
  );

}
```

In this case, I honestly think the easiest answer would be to create an `AppleToCherryConverter`. You could move the Apple to Banana and Banana to Cherry conversion routines into a single shared location for use by all three converters so that you are re-using the code:

```
Apple Apple { get; set; }
Cherry Cherry { get; set; }

...

void OnLoad() {

  SetBinding(
    "Cherry",
    new Binding("Apple") {
      Converter = (IValueConverter) FindResource("AppleToCherryConverter"),
      Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
    }
  );

}
```